# How to check if a user JID is already taken in XMPPFrameWork

Tags: ios, swift, xmppframework

I am kind of new to xmppframework. I have a quick question. Is it possible to know if a certain JID is available or no. In other words is it possible to check that the username is already associated or registered with certain account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with jabber search yes you can search and find user with specific jID or userName or ...

in here i create function that take some jID as a parameter and the server response to you as a query and inside that query if anythings match there will be items that contains user with matching jID

```
func xmppQueryForSearchPacket(forJID jid: String) {
    let searchingServer = "search.something" //something must replace with your xmpp domain name
    let query = DDXMLElement(name: "query", xmlns: "jabber:iq:search")
    let x = DDXMLElement(name: "x", xmlns: "jabber:x:data")
    x.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "submit")


    let field1 = DDXMLElement(name: "field")
    let value1 = DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: "jabber:iq:search")
    field1.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "hidden")
    field1.addAttribute(withName: "var", stringValue: "FORM_TYPE")
    field1.addChild(value1)


    let field2 = DDXMLElement(name: "field")
    let value2 = DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: jid)
    field2.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "text-single")
    field2.addAttribute(withName: "var", stringValue: "search")
    field2.addChild(value2)

    //we just search in userNames

    let field3 = DDXMLElement(name: "field")
    let value3 = DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: "1")
    field3.addAttribute(withName: "type", stringValue: "boolean")
    field3.addAttribute(withName: "var", stringValue: "Username")
    field3.addChild(value3)


    x.addChild(field1)
    x.addChild(field2)
    x.addChild(field3)
    query.addChild(x)


    let iq = XMPPIQ(iqType: .set, to: XMPPJID(string: searchingServer), elementID: XMPPStream.generateUUID, child: query)
   XMPPStream.send(iq)
}
```

the answer of that packet will come in a query form and you can receive it like this :

```
extension yourClassName: XMPPStreamDelegate {
    func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive iq: XMPPIQ) -> Bool {
        let searchingServer = "search.something"
        if iq.from?.bare != searchingServer {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

for more information please reade [XEP-0055](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0055.html).

Comment: HI thanks for the response but I received and error message from my server stating "No module is handling this query" do you know what module I shown enable

Comment: Hi, I think for this to work one should enable v_card module right ?

Comment: @Ahmed which server you are using ? if you are using Openfire in plugins you have to enable search module.if you are using ejabberd you should open configuration file in ejabberd directory and enable your search module and define some service name for it for examle search.ejabberd.no there is no need of v_card

Comment: I am using ejabberd and I set mod_vcard:
    search: true in my config file sorry what do you mean by a service name. Is it a subdomain. Where shall I include my service name in ejabberconfig file.

Comment: @Ahmed oh i,m sorry for ejabber you have to use mod_vcard to true and thats okay.something you have to know is that all of your user in ejabberd must declare their vcard. for doing this when your user log in and authenticate you have to send vcard to the server.another thing is that in my answer there is a searchingServer ,you should change it to = "vjud.something" and that something is your xmpp domain name

Comment: I got you so basically the user have to publish his vcard when authenticanted and then I can search his user name. I will try it soon thanks

Comment: @Ahmed yes all the user have to publish their vcard to the server and vjud.something service will query on the vcard for searching purposes

Comment: I was able to retrieve the vcard from server thanks for the help. is it possible to store retrieved vcard in core data using XMPPframework thank

Comment: please ask in another question.and specify your question.tnx

Comment: please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797335/saving-fetched-xmppframework-vcards-into-coredata-in-swift4 thanks in advance