# saving fetched XMPPframeWork vCards into CoreData in Swift4

Tags: ios, swift4, xmppframework, vcf-vcard

I was able to create and update a vCard using this code

```
    let xmppvCardStorage = XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage.sharedInstance()
    let xmppvCardTempModule = XMPPvCardTempModule.init(vCardStorage:xmppvCardStorage!)
    xmppvCardTempModule.activate(self.stream)
    xmppvCardTempModule.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    let vCard = DDXMLElement(name: "vCard", xmlns: "vcard-temp")
    let vCardTemp = XMPPvCardTemp.vCardTemp(from: vCard)
    vCardTemp.nickname = "john"
    vCardTemp.jid = XMPPJID(string: "john123@www.example.com")
```

Also I was able to fetch that vCard using the following code:

```
    let xmppvCardStorage = XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage.sharedInstance()
    let xmppvCardTempModule = XMPPvCardTempModule.init(vCardStorage: xmppvCardStorage!)
    xmppvCardTempModule.activate(self.stream)
    let jID = XMPPJID(string: "john@www.example.com")
    xmppvCardTempModule.addDelegate(self,delegateQueue:DispatchQueue.main)
    xmppvCardTempModule.fetchvCardTemp(for: jID!, ignoreStorage:false)
```

As you can see I am fetching the vCard from my server. This is done by setting `ignoreStorage` to `false`

My question is does the XMPPFrameWork support a way to store the retrieved vCards in CoreData such that I don't have to retrieve it every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchvCardTemp` simply fetches the vCardTemp for the given JID if it is not in the storage.when you set `ignoreStorage` to false you are saying that i don't want to use storage and i want to fetch it via the XMPPStream.
you should use just xmppvCardStorage and one of it's function called `vCardTempForJID` and simply pass your favorite jID and it will return it to you

Comment: I am setting it to false because when I set it to true there is nothing returned. Also , I tried what you said  but I am not getting anything 
here is my code snippet :
let xmppvCardStorage= XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage.sharedInstance() xmppvCardStorage?.vCardTemp(for: jid, xmppStream: self.stream).
My question is does the vCard get stored automatically in coreData when reterived or do I have to save it in the XMPPvCard.xcdatamodeld

Comment: no XMPPFramework implement coreData internally but you can implement it your self but there is no need of that.in `vCardTempForJID` there is an argument call `shouldFetch` and you should set it to true.because in first attempt it is empty and framework must fetch it via network but after filling it you can use it anywhere

Comment: thanks it works pretty ok just a quick thing. if vcard is stored now in my coreData file. shouldnot  the fetchVcard Method work while setting ignoring storage to true. If not so what is fetchVcard is used for then. Thanks

Comment: I don't get what you mean.`ignoreStorage` should set to false if you want fetchVcard do nothing.fetchVcard usage is when you are not sure that vCard is updated or not so you fetch via the xmppStream

Comment: My question is can I use this method fetchvCardTemp(for: jID!, ignoreStorage:false) instead of vCardTempForJID method. As far as I understand fetchvCardTemp(for: jID!, ignoreStorage:false) method can be user to check if vcard is in storage or no

Comment: ok thank if I use fetchvCardTemp(for: jID!, ignoreStorage:false) instead of vCardTempForJID method, I get nothing. I just wanted to know the difference. The  vCardTempForJID method is working fine but if I use  fetchvCardTemp(for: jID!, ignoreStorage:false) I get nothing thanks in advance

Comment: please confirm the answer if anything help you :)